# Typescript warning about property not present in one of the response types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a response coming back in the form:

```
const response : {
   a : string,
   b : string
} | {
   message : string
} = callFunc();
```

In my code, I am using this as:

```
response.message && doSomething(message);
```

However, typescript is screaming that property "message" does not exist on 1st type defined above. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `response` is a union type that may not have a `message` property you have to check it first

```
if ('message' in response) {
  doSomething(response.message)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to enter the message property on the 1st type json such as

const response : {
a : string,
b : string,
message:string
} | {
message : string
} = callFunc();